# How to use DetectAndDecodeMulti with gocv

Tags: opencv, go

This example code in python is working well.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('barcode.png')
qcd = cv2.QRCodeDetector()

retval, decoded_info, points, straight_qrcode = qcd.detectAndDecodeMulti(img)

print(decoded_info)
```

That gives me:

```
[[[ 52.       52.     ]
  [195.97902  52.     ]
  [198.5086  196.30678]
  [ 52.      196.     ]]]
('https://www.example.com',)
```

But I do not know how to use that in [gocv](https://gocv.io/). My attempt was:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func main() {
    qcd := gocv.NewQRCodeDetector()
    defer qcd.Close()
    codes := make([]string, 100)
    points := gocv.NewMat()
    qrcodes := make([]gocv.Mat, 100)
    img := gocv.IMRead("barcode.png", gocv.IMReadGrayScale)
    res := qcd.DetectAndDecodeMulti(img, &codes, &points, &qrcodes)
    fmt.Println(res)
    fmt.Println(points)
    fmt.Println(codes)
}
```

That gives:

```
true
{0x164a3b0 []}
g]                                                                                                   �
```

Probably I just handle my results in the wrong way, but I have no clue.

barcode.png:
[image: barcode example.com]

Comment: what errors do you get? [mre]

Comment: edited to fulfill the requirements - thanks

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with Go. can you poke around in the resulting objects? they're supposed to be either vectors/lists or cv::Mats, i.e. whatever that's equivalent to in Go. I found this wrapper code... https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/blob/5838ac14dc3ae2c5436c4133fbaab74b0dfe124a/objdetect.go#L262-L285

Answer (score 0):

Probably `gocv` tests can help you:

https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv/blob/release/objdetect_test.go

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).